# QuerySet, Object has no attribute 'zipCode' - Django

Tags: python, django, django-errors

Below is my code, which receiving an error

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'zipCode'

```
def feeds_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(id=request.COOKIES['id'])
    zipCode = profile.zipCode
```

when changing code to below receiving

> 'UserRegistration' object is not iterable:

```
def feeds_view(request):
    user = Profile.objects.get(id=request.COOKIES['id'])
    zipCode = user.zipCode
content = {
        'user': user
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/feeds.html', content)
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" name="feededBy" id="feededBy" value="{{user.displayName}}" hidden>
<input type="email" name="byEmailID" id="byEmailID" value="{{user.emailID}}" hidden>
```

Comment: Try printing what's in the profile varaible and see if u can actually access the attribute `zipCode`. It may be that it's just an iterable list

Comment: where you have defined and assigned the `user` object ?

Comment: It seems like you're no sharing the entire view code for the second case.

Comment: Sorry.. updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

`Profile.objects.filter(id=request.COOKIES['id'])` returns a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter). To access the actual object, use list indexing, like `profile[0].zipcode` after getting value in `profile`. Since you are just expecting a single object, it is better to use [get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get) method or [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) if applicable.

See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api) for introductory tutorial on this. You have to include more code for second error.